# make editText lose focus on back press

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my activity, I have a editText field. When the user taps on it, the editText gains the focus and the keyboard appears. Now, when the user presses the hardware back button on the phone, the keyboard disappears but the cursor remains in the Edittext, i. e., it still has the focus. Is it possible to make the EditText lose focus when back button is pressed? I tried using the following code but it didn't work:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    vibrator.vibrate(Constants.DEFAULT_VIBRATE_TIME);
    myEditText.clearFocus();
            super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: make sure myEditText  is not first input element in your layout.if yes then first remove Focus from EditText and then make focus to any other element like TextView etc

Comment: It was the first input element in my activity. I tried `title.requestFocus()` but it didn't work

Comment: first make title focusable then call title.requestFocus()

Comment: its still not loosing focus

Comment: Here is what you can use to hide keyboard without requiring a press on the back button (I know you want more btu that's still something)  :

this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: @PeterGriffin Yeah, I saw this on another question, but this does not achieve what I really want

Answer (score 24):

Just extend EditText:

```
public class EditTextV2 extends EditText
{
    public EditTextV2( Context context )
    {
        super( context );
    }

    public EditTextV2( Context context, AttributeSet attribute_set )
    {
        super( context, attribute_set );
    }

    public EditTextV2( Context context, AttributeSet attribute_set, int def_style_attribute )
    {
        super( context, attribute_set, def_style_attribute );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme( int key_code, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if ( key_code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP )
            this.clearFocus();

        return super.onKeyPreIme( key_code, event );
    }
}
```

And in the xml just use `<yourPackage.EditTextV2>` instead of `<EditText>`.

**Note:** You may need to add/remove constructors to this class depending on the min API you're supporting. I suggest just adding them all and removing the ones whose `super()` calls get underlined in red.

Comment: If we are to use the constructor: `EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)` minimum API requirement is 21 [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Comment: Perfectly elegant solution. Useful when you need to override the back button behavior using fragments using `View.OnKeyListener`, and need to capture a back button click event while a focus-stealing EditText interrupts your implementation. Cheers!

Comment: This is an amazing solution. THANKSSSSS!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can make another of your `Views` focusable, for example an `ImageView`. Be sure to make it focusable in touch mode, using `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` and on `onResume()` make that `View` to `requestFocus()`.

Also you can create a dummy `View` with 0 dimensions and perform same steps described above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using **Kotlin** and **Material Design**, you can use this:

```
class ClearFocusEditText: TextInputEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            clearFocus()
        }

        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add view like the following higher than your EditText:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Also to hide keyboard add this in onBackPressed():

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am providing  kotlin equivalent code to Kacy answer with some edit

```
class CustomSearch @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = 
null, defStyle: Int = 0):AppCompatEditText(context, attrs, defStyle) {
override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    val imm:InputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)
    this.clearFocus()
    //this.findFocus()
}
return true
}
```

Note: I am returning true and this is solving my problem i.e removing focus from edit text and hiding soft input

Answer (score -3):

This may be a possible solution:

```
EditText et;
et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                et.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    });
```